# Getting rid of /n from strings for Databases

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have figured out my Fighters ID cannot be loaded from the database because my path is incorrect.  This is because the string has a /n at the end of it that my database clearly does not have.  This is the code where the error occurs.

```
 func bronzePlayer () {
    loading.isHidden = false
    coverPacked.isHidden = false
    playerPackedCard.isHidden = false
    coverPackedCard.isHidden = false
    ref.child("Fighters/Bronze").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        self.packToNumber = value?["Total"] as! Int
        self.packedNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.packToNumber))) + 1
        self.setPackedString()

    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    ref.child("\(packedNumberString)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        self.playerPackedID = value?["ID"] as! Int
        self.playerPackedPicture = value?["Picture"] as? String ?? ""

        self.loading.isHidden = true

    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    playerPackedCard.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "\(playerPackedPicture)")
}
```

The error occurs where it says

```
  self.playerPackedID = value?["ID"] as! Int
```

This is because it is not finding

```
  ref.child("\(packedNumberString)")
```

I need to get rid of the /n at the end of that.  Any ideas on how?  Thanks!

Comment: Please paste output which you receive from firebase, and a screenshot of database for same ?

Comment: Can u please post the response string here , will be helpful to understand the issue better.

Comment: @SubratPadhi do you know what I would say instead of that answer as I said it was outdated?

Comment: Here's the issue. It appears that *packedNumberString* is being populated within the first observe closure. That closure is asynchronous and may not actually return with data to populate the packedNumberString before the second observe tries to use it. Also, this *ref.child("\(packedNumberString)")* is probably unnecessary if it's a string and may be be written as *ref.child(packedNumberString)* - also, that looks odd as it would be referring to *firebase_ref/xxxxxx* instead of it being a child node of another parent node. I could be wrong on that one...

Answer (score 2):

You can remove characters in String by using `filter` :

```
let filteredPackedNumberString = String(packedNumberString.characters.filter { !" \n".characters.contains($0) })
```

Then you can use the filtered string as the `child parameter` :

```
ref.child("\(filteredPackedNumberString)")
```

Comment: it says "characters" are depreciated.  What should I put instead? @MSyakir

Comment: While this is an answer, it's not a correct answer as it really doesn't address the actual problem. Also, use packedNumberString.filter directly with Swift 4 instead of .characters as it's depreciated.